# Why does a factory reset keep the operating system updated?

Tags: factory-reset

I recently did a factory reset to my phone and to my surprise, the operating system remained to the last updated version (6.0.0) and not the version I had when I bought the phone (5.0.0).

Why does this happen? Doesn't a factory reset reset the operating system too?

Comment: @beeshyams you're right.

Comment: That's fine - you got your answer from both :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

System updates overwrite `/system`. Factory reset wipes `/data` and `/cache` but doesn't touch `/system`. Simple as that.

Comment: can you backup /system to revert to an older version of android? Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: If you have a TWRP backup of an OS older version, it *can* work - emphasis on "can" because it might not be compatible with the newer baseband, vendor, etc. partitions if the versions are too far apart.