# Is "V10f-FEB-17-2017" update on LG K8 an upgrade to Android Nougat?

Tags: updates, 7.0-nougat, ota-update, lg

I have LG K8 on Android 6.0 Marshmallow. I went to [GSMarena](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_k8-7927.php) to check the specs and I noticed that it says that LG K8 is upgradable to 7.0 Nougat. I went to check for an update on my phone and there is an update available. It is 383.84MB large with version "V10f-FEB-17-2017".

[image]

I am not sure if this is the Nougat update because it only says Bug Fixes and Improvements and nothing else. I would install it, but I'm very short on space and don't want to waste 400MB for a bug fix update.

Can someone tell me if this is a Nougat update?

Comment: What is exact model of your phone? Is it something like k350xxx? Only T-Mobile verzion and MetroPCS variants of k8 got nougat, if we are talking about 2016. model

Comment: System updates do not occupy the space for user applications or data. These are updates in `/system` partition of your phone and the space utilised by downloading this update is released after update. For more see https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173903/does-a-new-software-update-take-up-more-space-or-replace-the-space-of-the-old-v

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's just bug fixes. I'm waiting for Nougat myself, and it should take about 1GB of your space.