# Should I do a factory reset or just change accounts when I give my phone to my mom?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, updates, motorola-moto-g

What's the best way to swap Android phones? I have an older Android phone (Moto G; Marshmallow) that I want to give my mom to use. She currently has an older Android phone.

So far I've only upgraded to brand new Androids from old Androids or just done factory resets to wipe out all data before I trash Androids. So I'm used to that. But this time its a different goal.

Should I be:

- Just doing a factory reset & then do an Android to Android transfer?
- Merely change the account associated with this phone?
- Some other way.

What's the recommended strategy? Any tips? Pitfalls?

PS. I've spent a day installing all the recommended updates to upgrade it all the way to Marshmallow. So if I can I don't want to lose that effort. Almost 700 MB of incremental upgrades.

Comment: I feel this is very opinion based. I'd prefer a clean factory reset, but I think this is a person to person thing

Comment: @curious_cat Doing factory reset will remove android updates and restore the phone back to packing condition.

Comment: @WrichikBasu I request you follow the link to understand the factory reset a bit better. https://android.stackexchange.com/q/155185/96277 :)